# I't to know if i can hide my identity from world to do my social causes near me

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, proxy, browsers

I'm running Tor in Windows. Getting error "Unable to find Proxy for private or normal mode".

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I'd to know if I can hide my identity from world to do my social causes near me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the proxy server - like 127.0.0.1 9050 socks5